# MySQL - Max Value of Column to Calculate against ALL records in Same Column

Tags: mysql

What is the proper syntax for using the MAX value from a column to calculate against all other records in that same column?

```
SELECT latitude,longitude,(variableData / MAX(variableData)) * 10 AS weightedData FROM heatMapData GROUP BY uniqueID;
```

With the example I have provided, the MAX of the column variableData is returning itself for each record as I have a result of 10 for weightedData.

For the record, the table heatMapData that I provided in my example consists of 4 columns:

1. uniqueID - VARCHAR(255)
2. latitude - DECIMAL(8,6)
3. longitude - DECIMAL(9,6)
4. variableData - DECIMAL(17,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method utilizing `JOIN` and `user variable` to keep the max value, guaranteeing that the `MAX()` is only executed once.

```
SELECT latitude,longitude,(variableData / @max_var_data) * 10 AS weightedData 
FROM heatMapData CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT @max_var_data := (SELECT MAX(variableData) FROM heatMapData)) params
GROUP BY uniqueID;
```

Answer (score 1):

A user-defined variable (as shown in the selected answer) isn't necessary.

As an alternative:

```
SELECT h.latitude
     , h.longitude
     , h.variableData / m.max_vd * 10 AS weightedData
  FROM heatMapData h
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT MAX(d.variableData) AS max_vd
           FROM heatMapData d
       ) m
 GROUP BY h.uniqueID
```

NOTE:

Some databases other than MySQL would throw an error with statement, due to the non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list that are not included in the GROUP BY. A MySQL-specific extension to GROUP BY behavior allows the query to run, but we can make MySQL conform more closely to the standard (and throw an error), by adding ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to the sql_mode variable.

Comment: Well Noted. Could you comment on why it would be preferred to not have a user-defined variable? I have my assumptions as to why but believe it would be better if you could clarify rather than assume.

Comment: The user-defined variable pattern is specific to MySQL, so SQL written this way isn't as portable to other databases. Also, the value of a user-defined variable is defined at the session level, and is evaluated when it is accessed. If we were to write a function e.g. foo which modifies the value of the variable, if we use the function in the SQL statement, there's no guarantee that the variable will have the same value for each row, when the expression in the SELECT list is evaluated. And user-defined variables are stored as strings, not as a specific datatype.

Comment: Well noted again! Thank You!

Comment: If we misspell the variable name in one place or the other so it doesn't match, then it's references to two different variables. MySQL won't throw an error, the outer SELECT will use a different value than the one assigned in the inline view. No error, but incorrect/unexpected results. If we do the same thing with the column alias, then MySQL throws an error, I also thing the user-defined variables add unnecessary obfuscation for the reader, who will likely ask "why is a user-defined variable necessary here?"

Comment: User-defined variables are a powerful feature, and they are almost indispensable in some situations. I prefer to reserve the use of user-defined variables to cases where they provide an actual benefit.